# Implementation of 'imquantize' function in opencv

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I  am  trying  to  implement   the  Matlab  function  imquantize  using opencv. Which  opencv  thresholding  function  I  should  use  to  implement  Matlab  function  multithresh?  Once  thresholding  has  been  done  how  do  I  label  the pixels  according  to  the  threshold? Is  this  the  right  way  to  implement   imquantize ? Are  there  any  other  function's    I  should  include   in  the  code?

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation based on OpenCV [here](https://github.com/dapicester/image-search/blob/master/libvis/src/hsv_aux.cpp#L107), where you should probably get the idea:

```
cv::Mat
imquantize(const cv::Mat& in, const arma::fvec& thresholds) {
    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(cv::DataType<float>::type == in.type(), "input is not of type float");

    cv::Mat index(in.size(), in.type(), cv::Scalar::all(1));
    for (int i = 0; i < thresholds.size() ; i++) {
        cv::Mat temp = (in > thresholds(i)) / 255;
        temp.convertTo(temp, cv::DataType<float>::type);
        index += temp;
    }

    return index;
}
```

**Updated**: *`thresholds` are the vector of the float threshold values (uniform distributed to `# of levels` that you want to quantize within `[0, 1]`).* Check [the code snippet](https://github.com/dapicester/image-search/blob/master/libvis/src/hsv_aux.cpp#L84) of how it is used:

```
const float step = 1./levels[i];
arma::fvec thresh = arma::linspace<arma::fvec>(step, 1.-step, levels[i]-1);
channels[i] = imquantize(channels[i], thresh);
```

Comment: Sorry to ask you. From where I get this 'thresholds'?

Comment: 'thresholds'  is  a  n by 1 matrix. Is it right?  How can I make this matrix?

Comment: @user3440725 I have updated the answer to make it clear.

Comment: @herohuyongato: I thought 'level' is a single digit  value. But here it is a vector,right? Can you please give me example  for 'level'  value?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like this

```
    /*function imquantize
    * 'inputImage' is the input image.
    * 'levels' is an array of threholds
    * 'quantizedImage' is the reurned image  
    *  with quantized levels. 
    */
Mat imquantize(Mat inputImage, vector<vector<int> > levels)
{     
    //initialise output label matrix
    Mat quantizedImage(inputImage.size(), inputImage.type(), Scalar::all(1));    

    //Apply labels to the pixels according to the thresholds
    for (int i = 0; i < inputImage.cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputImage.rows; j++)
        {
            // Check if image is grayscale or BGR
            if(levels.size() == 1)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < levels[0].size(); k++) 
                {
                    // if pixel < lowest threshold , then assign 0
                    if(inputImage.at<uchar>(j,i) <= levels[0][0])
                    { 
                        quantizedImage.at<uchar>(j,i) = 0;
                    }

                    // if pixel > highest threshold , then assign 255
                    else if(inputImage.at<uchar>(j,i) >= levels[0][levels[0].size()-1]) 
                    { 
                        quantizedImage.at<uchar>(j,i) = 255;
                    }

                    // Check the level borders for pixel and assign the corresponding
                    // upper bound quanta to the pixel
                    else
                    { 
                        if(levels[0][k] < inputImage.at<uchar>(j,i) && inputImage.at<uchar>(j,i) <= levels[0][k+1])
                        {
                            quantizedImage.at<uchar>(j,i) = (k+1)*255/(levels[0].size());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Vec3b pair = inputImage.at<Vec3b>(j,i); 

                // Processing the Blue Channel
                for (int k = 0; k < levels[0].size(); k++) 
                {
                    if( pair.val[0] <= levels[0][0]) 
                    {
                        quantizedImage.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[0] = 0;
                    }
                    else if( pair.val[0] >= levels[0][levels.size()-1])
                    {
                        quantizedImage.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[0] = 255; 
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        if(levels[0][k] < pair.val[0] && pair.val[0] <= levels[0][k+1]) 
                        {
                            quantizedImage.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[0] = (k+1)*255/(levels[0].size());
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Processing the Green Channel
                for (int k = 0; k < levels[1].size(); k++) 
                {
                    if( pair.val[1] <= levels[1][0]) 
                    {
                        quantizedImage.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[1] = 0;
                    }
                    else if( pair.val[1] >= levels[1][levels.size()-1])
                    {
                        quantizedImage.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[1] = 255; 
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        if(levels[1][k] < pair.val[1] && pair.val[1] <= levels[1][k+1]) 
                        {
                            quantizedImage.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[1] = (k+1)*255/(levels[1].size());
                        }
                    }   
                }

                // Processing the Red Channel
                for (int k = 0; k < levels[2].size(); k++) 
                {
                    if( pair.val[2] <= levels[2][0]) 
                    {
                        quantizedImage.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[2] = 0;
                    }
                    else if( pair.val[2] >= levels[2][levels.size()-1])
                    {
                        quantizedImage.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[2] = 255; 
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        if(levels[2][k] < pair.val[2] && pair.val[2] <= levels[2][k+1]) 
                        {
                            quantizedImage.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[2] = (k+1)*255/(levels[2].size());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return quantizedImage;
}
```

In this function the input had to be an Mat::Image and a 2D vector which can have different levels for different channels.